# Парсинг сайта с загруженым js

Tags: c#, html, синтаксический-анализ, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо получить HTML код страницы после того как страница загрузиться и JS внесет в нее изменения.

Чем ток не пробовал WebClient HttpWebRequest , загружается тело функций JS но никак не обработанный им код.

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Тело функций? Обработанный им код? Шито?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте Selenium/Webdriver.

Comment: phantom ещё